# How do you pass post form variables in ASP.NET C#/Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post, razor

I'm new to C#/Razor and don't know how to pass form data using the post method. Here's what I've tried:

In login.cshtml:

```
string username = Request.Form["username"];
string password = Request.Form["password"];
```

And

```
string username = Request.Form.Get("username");
string password = Request.Form.Get("password");
```

In _AppStart.cshtml, I tried:

```
AppState["username"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["username"];
AppState["password"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["password"];
```

All return nothing.

Here's the form elements in login.cshtml:

```
<form action="index.cshtml" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's currently no MVC methods yet. I'm trying to pass data like it would do in a general website with server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass data between MVC controller and View then you have to let Asp know which action an controller  to call.

To accomplish this you could  use something like BeginForms in razor an specify the needed information.

This would look like this:

```
    @Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post){ 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(employee => employee.FirstName);
      @Html.TextBoxFor(employee => employee.LastName);
      @Html.TextBoxFor(employee => employee.Age);
      <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    }
```

Following this snippet you can see that you need A Controller and you name an ActionResult according to the name given here furthermore you can specify if you want to have the action only when posting or only for get forms

An possibile exemple could be the edit like the following code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction(Employee emp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do smth.
        }

        return View("Name Of the view");
    }
```

Note you need to define this in your Controller and that the Attribute HttpPost lets Asp know that this is a post only ActionResult. This means that only post requests can use this Method. Furthermore

if you wish to have both get and post requests available for this ActionResult then you can simply delete the Attribute then per default it will be available in get and set requests.

You could look at this forum 
[entry](https://forums.asp.net/t/1922349.aspx?Posting%20data%20from%20view%20to%20controller%20MVC)

Answer (score 0):

in Input Type "submit add formaction="ActionMethodName"

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
        <input type="file" name="postedFile"/>
        <input type="submit"  **formaction="UploadData"** value="UploadData"/>

   }
```